# Using @SecondaryTables but having the fields themselves in separate classes

Tags: jpa

My Entity is spread across separate tables and the most common sense approach for me is to use @SecondaryTables. But what I do not like about using @SecondaryTables is that the fields of the second / third tables also have to be in the same Entity Java class. Because the second/third tables have a lot of fields, putting them all together will make it a humongous class.

Is there a way, in which I could use @SecondaryTables but physically place the fields in different classes. What would have been awesome is have something like

```
 @SecondaryTables({
    @SecondaryTable(name="Table2", 
        pkJoinColumns=@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="ID_2"), class="someclass")
})
```

But JPA does not provide such a facility
It only does not provide class="someclass" attribute..

So is there any way to do what I wish for?

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do is to use an embeddable:

```
@Entity
public class SomeEntity {

    @Embedded
    private SomeOtherClass someOtherClass; //mappings for table 2
}

@Embeddable
public class SomeOtherClass {

    // define columns from table 2
    @Column(table = "Table2")
    public String someColumn;
}
```